# PHP variable value changing unexpectedly in For Else statement

Tags: php, if-statement

In the following loop the first var_dump is int(2).  In the last var_dump the value is int(0).  I don't understand where the value of $total_gals changes.

```
<?php
$total_gals  = count( glob("images/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) ); 
$loadnum = 0;
var_dump($total_gals);
if ($total_gals = 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('No Galleries to Load');</script>";
    var_dump($total_gals);
} elseif ($total_gals > 5) {
    $loadnum = 5;
} else {
    $loadnum == $total_gals;
}
var_dump($total_gals);
?>
```

Comment: Check you if statement replace this with `if ($total_gals = 0)` with `if ($total_gals == 0)`

Comment: In first if statement you use one equal (=) you should use (==)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `if ($total_gals = 0) {` needs to be `if ($total_gals == 0) {`

Without the second = you're assigning 0 to the variable which always evaluates to true for the if statement.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 0):

First if you’re reassigning `total_gals` to `0`, and it’s obviously true statement

```
   if ($total_gals = 0) {
```